# htaccess; mod_rewrite; Redirect to folder twice

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my homepage-files are located in example.com/index/. So when I go to example.com I see the content from example.com/index/ (without having example.com/index/ in the url)

I found this and it is working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index/$1 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index/ [L]
```

Question: I have some projects on my domain and I would like to store them at example.com/live/PROJECT/. So, when I type example.com/PROJECT, I will that he looks up the files in example.com/live/PROJECT. It is the same in some way like the thing above with /index but I don't get it.

For some hours I have tried to figure it out but I don't know how to do this. Maybe you can help me with this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You cannot use 2 targets for same URI pattern `^(.*)$`